# Read strings until an integer appears

Tags: java, string

I need to read the contents of a file. The file contains the names various foods and information regarding portions:

```
Name:                         Portions:
APPLE JUICE, CANNED           1 CUP
APPLE PIE                     1 PIE
```

How can I read the entire name of a food item without including the portions?

Comment: How did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you written any code?

Comment: The best approach would be to use a regular expression. See the java.util.regex package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have your streams set up and reading, (and a space is your delimiter), you could do something like this:

```
while((line = stream.readLine()) != null)
{
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    for(int index = 0; index < words.length; index++)
    {
        if(isNumeric(words[index]))
        {
            //you found a number. do something here;
        }
    }
}
```

defining the function here: [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java)

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
  try  
  {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the chars of the strings and check if the [ascii](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) code is a number. Where the numbers have the ascii codes 48 to 57. To get the acsii code of a char do the following:

```
char c = 'A';
int ascii = (int)c;
System.out.println(ascii); //prints 65
```

So the whole code would look like:

```
public int getIndexOfNumber(String s){
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        int ascii = (int)s.charAt(i);
        if(ascii >= 48 && ascii <= 57)
            return i;
    }
    return -1; //not found
}
```